# Error when creating objects using TclOO

Tags: oop, tcl

I have Tcl 8.6 installed on my system. I am just trying some examples from [TIP #257: Object Orientation for Tcl](http://wiki.tcl.tk/14754) :

```
oo::object create foo
::foo
oo::define foo {method bar {} {puts "Hello, World!"}}
foo does not refer to a class
while evaluating {oo::define foo {method bar {} {puts "Hello, World!"}}}
```

I thought that I can just create an object without class, or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The example might have worked with early versions of the implementation, but configuration of instances was moved to a separate command, `oo::objdefine`, to make the code a bit less crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `objdefine` instead of `define` to work on objects.

Note that a class is an object, so when you work on the class *itself* you still use `objdefine`.

Some of the examples on the wiki (and one in the documentation for the Tcllib `oo::util` module) were written while TclOO was still taking shape and are not executable under the current definition of the system. Another problem is that some wiki pages describe clever workarounds for TclOO limitations that have since been eliminated and no longer need any workarounds, so if you're learning TclOO from the wiki you will be confused. If anyone knows a good, up-to-date tutorial, feel free to comment with links.

(I just remembered [this](http://www.magicsplat.com/articles/oo.html) book chapter. I haven't studied it in detail, but it did clear a couple of things up for me.)

Documentation: [oo::define](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/define.htm) (also `objdefine`), [oo::util](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/ooutil/ooutil.html) package

Comment: If there are examples in the TclOO documentation (== the TclOO parts of the Tcl 8.6 documentation) that are not correct, let me know and I *will* fix them ASAP. Wiki pages can just be fixed by anyone. Other resources will vary in difficultly (and Final TIPs won't be touched).

Comment: @DonalFellows: the example I was thinking of turned out to be in the `oo::util` docs (the singleton example) and not in the core TclOO docs. OTOH, that documentation glitch was reported 2½ years ago... ([ticket](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/tktview?name=3609183fff)) As for the wiki, I refuse to touch it in the current state of affairs.

Comment: @DonalFellows: actually, there *are* a couple of incorrect examples in the core docs as well. When you say "let me know", do I send them to you personally or do I file tickets somewhere?

Comment: I've submitted two tickets to `core.tcl.tk` now. There didn't seem to be any documentation category, so I marked them as TclOO and put "documentation: " in the heading.